# Trying to boot from usb

Tags: usb

I am using an HP Probook 4540s which currently has Ubuntu 12.10 on it. I hit escape to go to which drive to boot from, and when i manage to choose the usb I get something like "Insane primary partition (mbr) I cant find myself from what you are trying to boot from.
boot:" Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using dd to send the iso image to usb drive

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso/image of=/dev/sdb bs=8M
```

Is so important that add the bs=8M to make it work!
And check that /dev/sdb is the device where you have the usb flash drive
do it with

```
df -h
```